# google predicate API Refresh token exception

Tags: php, google-api, oauth-2.0, prediction

I have to use Google Predicate API for a project so I m playing the "Hello Prediction" sample first https://developers.google.com/prediction/docs/hello_world

I want to use Service account  auth method in order to call the API directly from my web server

Here is my script, I always get a

```
Google_AuthException Object
(
    [message:protected] => Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{
  "error" : "invalid_grant"
}
```

Any suggestions?

```
            <?php
            ini_set('display_errors',1);
            error_reporting(E_ALL);

            require_once 'google-api-php-client/Google_Client.php';
            require_once 'google-api-php-client/contrib/Google_PredictionService.php';

            session_start();

            $client = new Google_Client();

            define("CLIENT_ID", 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com');
            define("SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME", 'Prediction API Project');
            define("KEY_FILE", 'google-api-php-client/xxxxxxxxcd-privatekey.p12');

            $client = new Google_Client();
            $key = file_get_contents(KEY_FILE);


            $client->setAssertionCredentials(new Google_AssertionCredentials(
                                        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME,
                                        array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control'),
                                        $key));

            $client->setClientId(CLIENT_ID);

            $predictionService = new Google_PredictionService($client);
            $trainedmodels = $predictionService->trainedmodels;


                $id = "languageidentifier";
                $predictionText = "Je suis vraiment très très fatigué";
                $predictionData = new Google_InputInput();
               $predictionData->setCsvInstance(array($predictionText));
                $input = new Google_Input();
                 $input->setInput($predictionData);
                try{
                $result = $predictionService->trainedmodels->predict($id, $input);
                print("<h2>Prediction Result:</h2>");
                print_r($result);
                }

                catch (Exception $e)
                {
                    echo '<pre>';
                    print_r($e);
                    echo '</pre>';
                }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was missing the prediction in the scopes

```
$client->setAssertionCredentials(new Google_AssertionCredentials(
                        EMAIL_ADDRESS,
                        array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction'),
                        $key));
```

it s ok now